# Pulling data from SQL based on the amount of days between 2 dates

Tags: php, sql, phpmyadmin, datediff

I have a STUDENT table in SQL with a 'DATE' (2018-04-23) formatted column called 'DateCompleted'

What I'm trying to do is pull any students who have a 'DateComplete' date that is less than 5 days from today's date.

I've found a lot of questions on here answering small parts of what I need and this is what I have so far. The code runs, but nothing happens.

```
$getToday = date("Y-m-d");

$SQLstring = "SELECT * FROM STUDENT WHERE Department='" . $dept . "'";

$SQLGetCompleted = "AND (DATEDIFF(d, " . strtotime($getToday) . ", DateCompleted) < 5")

$db_selected = mysqli_query($con, $SQLstring . $SQLGetCompleted);
```

DATEDIFF is supposed to return the number of days between today and the DateCompleted, and then if its less than 5 days

NOTE: $getToday has to be a string that is formatted within the SQL string otherwise it will error out if you try to put a date value in a string.

Comment: You might like to put a space before the `"AND ...` like `" AND.....`

Comment: Do you get error messages? Or just not the data you expect

Comment: Add `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` to
the top of your script. This will force any `mysqli_` errors to
generate an Exception that you can see on the browser and other errors will also be visible on your browser.

Comment: Nothing errors out, I'm running in browser and it seems to run through just fine

Comment: Are you actually testing for and then displaying errors?

Answer (score 2):

First, you should learn to use parameters.  Second, your query would look like one of the following.

For anything in the last five days:

```
where datecompleted >= curdate() - interval 5 days and
      datecompleted <= curdate()  -- may not be needed
```

For anything in an 11 day period (5 before, 5 after, today).

```
where datecompleted >= curdate() - interval 5 days and
      datecompleted < curdate() + interval 5 days
```

If `datecompleted` actually has a time component, then you need to be a bit more careful.  Your sample data suggests that it is just a date.

Comment: this isn't really a `php` question at all: were it to have been he also needs to use prepared statements, so this answer helps with that in that it makes it a `MySQL` only answer

Comment: I removed the extra parameter. Does curdate() return todays date in YYYY-mm-dd?

Comment: @Ken . . . That is the ANSI/ISO standard format for dates.

Answer (score 1):

```
AND (DATE(DateCompleted) - fn Now()) < 5
```

OR

```
AND DATE(DateCompleted)  <  fn Now() - 5
```

OR

```
AND DATE(DateCompleted)  <  GETDATE() - 5
```

Comment: What does `fn Now()` mean? That does not look like valid SQL

Comment: Hold up, I think this guys answer worked. except instead of now I used CURDATE(). I managed to get data within the parameters I was asking

Comment: This worked:  AND DateCompleted >= CURDATE() - 5. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Glad it worked :). Nico, fn NOW() is a non standard SQL command, does the same as CURDATE